# Save Locations of Multiple Points of the First Frame

Tags: python, opencv

I have video of the cowhouse. I want to get the corners of the food container in the middle of the that. I was trying to accomplish the task in the following steps -

```
1. Freeze the video into the first frame (done using waitkey set to 0)
2. Pass the first frame into draw_circle function to get the corners
3. Play the video regularly after the first frame (done using changing waitkey value)
```

However, I can't accomplish the second objectives. When the frame freezes I clicked multiple points but still the mouse list is empty. Is there any way to do that? The codes are provided below -

```
# import libraries
import cv2, numpy as np

# the point location will be saved into the mouse list
mouse = []

# define the function to get point location
def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),100,(255,0,0),-1)
        ix,iy = x,y
        mouse.append([x,y])

# waitKey to freeze the video into the first frame
waitKey = 0


cap = cv2.VideoCapture("L2_clip2_16s.m4v")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        cv2.imshow("res",frame)

        # the first frame will be freezed and go through the draw_circle function
        if waitKey ==0:
            cv2.setMouseCallback("imshow",draw_circle)

        key = cv2.waitKey(waitKey)

        # when done taking point - click c to assign the value to waitkey and play the video normally
        if key == ord("c"):
            waitKey = 1

        elif key== ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print (mouse)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process is as follows:
- create a new window
- attach a mouseCallback
- draw frames to this window
- when you click in the window the draw_circle function is called
- to process the frame, use the frame variable
- to see the changes, redraw the frame

The mouseCallback needs to be attached only once.
Note: `print (mouse)` in your code is never reached, because of the `while`loop.

I've modified your code, so that it works. I only left comments where I modified the code.

```
import cv2, numpy as np

mouse = []

def draw_circle(event,x,y,flags,param):
    global ix,iy
    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
        # draw dot where double clicked
        cv2.circle(frame,(x,y),5,(0,0,255),-1)
        ix,iy = x,y
        mouse.append([x,y])
        # redraw frame to screen - with circle
        cv2.imshow("Video",frame)
        # print coordinates
        print (mouse)


waitKey = 0
# open a window named 'video'
cv2.namedWindow("Video")
# attach mouseCallback to the window named 'video'
cv2.setMouseCallback("Video",draw_circle)

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("L2_clip2_16s.m4v")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        # draw the frame in the window named 'Video'
        cv2.imshow("Video",frame)

        key = cv2.waitKey(waitKey)

        if key == ord("c"):
            waitKey = 1
        elif key== ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```